# Code is HttpClient or servlet API to parse Cookie header

Tags: http, header, cookies, httpclient

Is there any existing code in Apache HttpClient or in the servlet API to parse Cookie header and obtain from a string that contains "name1=value1; name2=value2; ..." a list of Cookie? Writing code to parse this doesn't seem too hard, but if there is already some existing code, I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call [getCookies()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) on the `HttpServletRequest` object, it will return an array of `Cookie` objects.  If you need to frequently look up cookies by name, then it may be easier to put them in to a Map so it's easy to look them up (rather than iterate over the Array each time).  Something like this:

```
public static Map<String,Cookie> getCookieMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    HashMap<String,Cookie> cookieMap = new HashMap<String,Cookie>();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            cookieMap.put(cookie.getName(), cookie);
        }
    }
    return cookieMap;
}
```

If you're using HttpClient and not servlets, you can get the `Cookie` array using:

```
client.getState().getCookies()
```

where client is your HttpClient object.

Comment: This assumes that the Servlet API is available on classpath.  Vert.x doesn't use HttpServletRequest.