# how to parse raw cookie

Tags: java, http, cookies

How can I parse the raw cookie string.

It must return the javax.servlet.http.Cookie object.

The raw cookie like this:

```
Set-Cookie: BAIDUID=66AA214F9A534411A339CE5E60D36E28:FG=1; expires=Sun, 05-Aug-42 06:41:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.baidu.com
```

Comment: Search first!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366214/code-is-httpclient-or-servlet-api-to-parse-cookie-header

Comment: I want to parse by myself..  Parse the cookie string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what is the difficulty you face - What have you tried ?

- `String[] pairs = String.split(";")` will give you an array of name-value pairs.
- On each name-value pair, `pair.subString(0, pair.indexOf(':') + 1)` will give you the name
- `pair.subString(pair.indexOf(':') + 1, pair.length - (pair.indexOf(':') + 1))` will give you the value
- pull out `pair.indexOf(':')` into a variable and reuse